# Mathematica: Sum with more than 250 summands in table leads to slow computation

Tags: sum, wolfram-mathematica

I am encountering a rather strange behavior in Mathematica when having sums with more than 250 summands in tables. I actually want to compute and tabularize a rather straightforward moving average over an array of numbers, but want to do so without relying on Mathematica's `MovingAverage`, since I want to change it later to do moving averages over different powers and functions of the sample data.

A minimal working example would be the following:

```
inputdata=RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[],100000];
average[n_, j_,data_]:=Sum[data[[k]],{k,n-j,n+j}]/(2j+1)
averagetable=With[{$j=100},Table[{n,average[n,$j,inputdata]},{n,1000,5000}]];
ListPlot[averagetable]
```

Now, as long as `$j` is smaller or less than 124, this executes pretty much instantly (0.7 seconds). However, as soon as I increase `$j` to 125 or more, the same operation takes three minutes. Since the only thing that changes between these two cases is the number of summands (249 in the first case, 251 in the latter), I guess there is some difference in how Mathematica handles sums of different length. What is the reason for this, and how would I work around this problem?

EDIT: Thanks to acl for answering the question. The `CompileLength`, in this case `SumCompileLength`, option indeed does the trick, now everything works as expected.

Comment: `SystemOptions["CompileOptions"]` shows that `TableCompileLength` is 250. Maybe `SetSystemOptions[
 "CompileOptions" -> {"TableCompileLength" -> Infinity}]` will help (maybe not, I haven't tried)

Comment: glad you found an answer, however i suspect you'll do even better if you work with `Partition` and `Map`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this result more efficiently using  `MovingAverage`.

```
inputdata = RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], 100000];

average[n_, j_, data_] := Sum[data[[k]], {k, n - j, n + j}]/(2 j + 1)

t1 = Timing[
   averagetable = 
     With[{$j = 100}, 
      Table[{n, average[n, $j, inputdata]}, {n, 1000, 5000}]];][[1]]
```

> 1.241809

```
t2 = Timing[
   averagetable2 = 
     Thread[{Range[1000, 5000], 
       MovingAverage[inputdata[[900 ;; 5100]], 201]}];][[1]]
```

> 0.002761

```
t1/t2
```

> 450.

```
(averagetable - averagetable2) // Chop[#, 10^-15] & // Union
```

> {{0, 0}}